# ASP.Net aspxerrorpath=/Login.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently uploaded my asp.net website to a hosting server. But now when I query the URL: http://paracha.net/ it gives me a 404 error. This 404 error page is rendering from my own specified custom error in Web.config

[Snapshot of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjgw.png)

I am scratching my head about the problem, searched alot but no luck. This is my really first asp.net website that I am trying to host online. It works great on localhost. I created it from scratch.

I don't know what I have done wrong thats causing the error. Any help would be appreciated. The contents of my Web.config file are listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="6PxGIlfmR+SIQQeQxclyvZkdYPeZCxACddWp3Xo8UmzL3ySf3l88buc8VEZkmH/pztsiJqd687ma1RmcwG9OEwd72O12ak5Nhn6Ulcjy20M=" />
    <add key="EncryptionKey" value="BD3/VpyzkrX//Mn2FWQev0yHUvftOQGr" />
    <add key="LogPath" value="C:\Logs\" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home/Home.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <urlMappings>
      <add url="~/Home/" mappedUrl="~/Home/Home.aspx" />
      <add url="~/Home/ItemStock/" mappedUrl="~/Home/Home.aspx" />
    </urlMappings>
  <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages></system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: try <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full" />

Comment: It looks like the `Login.aspx` file may not exist on your server - can you check that?

Comment: I uploaded all the files using Filezilla and also verified the existence of files on the server. They are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I found the problem.

As @Manraj said I tried:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

After refreshing the page I saw that SQL Server is unable to login with default user "sa", So I quickly realized that the database connection string is not correct. I changed the connection string. and It works fine now. :)

Tip for people who might face this problem. **customErrors** override the original error details and hide the stack trace as well. So If you are facing some sort of error try to turn off **customErrors** then check whats the actual error.

Thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

It seems some exception has occurred in the application and it has been redirected to  the error page. This will usually happen when the application moves from development environment to production environment. If you are using any error logs check the error log for the exception or remove the custom error tag and see what exactly the error is and rectify it. The ultimate thing is you have to find out what is the exception and rectify it. If you not using any error log try using error log like log4net and log the exceptions.

Comment: Can anybody explain why this answer is downvoted? except the part remove custom error instead of 'off' the answer is legitimate.The run time exception has occurred an asked to find it.